# How to compare the characters in beginning of the string without including trailing numbers or characters

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I need to find the next highest number, minus the characters I'm searching; from a column of codes.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT `code` 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `code` LIKE 'CR%' 
ORDER BY `code` DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

This works great if all the codes are like so:

```
CR52334
CR52333
CR52332
```

However there are instances where the codes are like this and there is more then two characters:

```
CRO6506
CRI3422
CR52334
CR52333
CR52332
```

This skews my results. I only want rows that start with "CR" and then a number.

Mysql Version: `Server version: 5.6.10-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)`

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: `Server version: 5.6.10-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)`

Comment: `I only want rows that start with CR and then a number` -- Do you mean, do you want to ignore rows that start with CRO and CRI?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Anything CR and then a number with nothing in between.

Comment: Can't you just filter out the other rows with the following predicate: `where substring(code, 3, 1) in ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the `REGEXP` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp), which is available in MySQL 5.6:

```
where code regexp '^CR[0-9]+$'
```

Regex breakdown:

```
^        beginning of the string
CR       literal string 'CR'
[0-9]+   any number of digits (at least one)
$        end of the string
```

You can be more specific - say you want exactly 5 digits:

```
where code regexp '^CR[0-9]{5}$'
```

Comment: @KevinJ: my bad - it is spelled `REGEXP`, not `REGEX`. Fixed.

Comment: Ah I see the typo now.

Comment: This works amazing, now I have a new issue with the sorting. CR9048 comes up before CR19128. Maybe I can try using `BIN()`.

Comment: This seems to do the trick ```SELECT `code` FROM `users` WHERE `code` regexp '^CR[0-9]+$' ORDER BY LENGTH(code) DESC, code DESC```